# Why didn't the Atreides family extensively watch this character in such a period of tension?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

I just saw the movie *Dune* (2021), and I also read the first book a few years ago.
I was surprised that one of the closest persons of the Atreides' family, Dr. Yueh, didn't get any surveillance, such that they were not aware his wife was captured by the enemy Harkonnen (moreover in a period of great tension).

Is there any explanation later on in the work or is it just incoherent?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In brief, Yueh is a person who is supposedly *above* any consideration of malice or duplicity toward his patients, the house Atreides, because of the conditioning that Doctors from the Suk School receive.

> **IMPERIAL CONDITIONING:** *a development of the Suk Medical Schools: the highest conditioning against taking human life.*
>
> <sub><sup>Dune</sup></sub>

There's no point investigating him as a potential traitor *beyond confirming that he's the real Yueh.*

> “Hawat will have divined that we have an agent planted on him,” Piter said. “The obvious suspect is Dr. Yueh, who is indeed our agent. **But Hawat has investigated and found that our doctor is a Suk School graduate with Imperial Conditioning — supposedly safe enough to minister even to the Emperor. Great store is set on Imperial Conditioning. It’s assumed that ultimate conditioning cannot be removed without killing the subject.** However, as someone once observed, given the right lever you can move a planet. We found the lever that moved the doctor.”
>
> <sub><sup>Dune</sup></sub>

Even when it becomes ***blindingly obvious to anyone with eyes*** that Yueh must be the traitor, Paul still can't understand what's happening. He thinks he's mistaken, or that it's some manner of ruse.

> He wondered who could’ve captured her. His own captivity was plain
> enough– to bed with a capsule prescribed by Yueh, awaking to find
> himself bound to this litter. Perhaps a similar thing had befallen
> her. **Logic said the traitor was Yueh, but he held final decision in
> abeyance. There was no understanding it–a Suk doctor a traitor.**

Comment: But it's unlike Hawat to actually not investigate Yueh's wife. Here question is very good, but of course even book is mum about that beyond the fact that he knows she is dead, killed by Harkonnens (which, to give credit to Thufir, would make Yueh MORE trustworthy, but still)...

Comment: AcePL - It's not a question of his being more or less trustworthy, it's that his trustworthiness is already *absolute.*

Comment: I agree in principle. However, this is Thufir Hawat we're talking about. you know, Mentat Assasin? Mentat supposedly doesn't know the meaning of the word "absolute". Everyone else should be fine with common knowledge on Suk Conditioning, but not him... That's why this part of the question fascinates me...

Comment: @AcePL - Once something is an established fact, it becomes very easy to overlook that there might be an outlier.

Comment: @AcePL - consider that the scheme was devised by another Mentat: Piter. He states: "Is it not sublime? Hawat's mind will be so filled with this prospect [Jessica as traitor] that *it will impair his function as a Mentat*" - So basically, leveraging a Suk doctor was already considered effectively impossible AND they drug a much more likely candidate across Hawat's path since he already mistrusted the "Bene-Gesserit witches". He was simply outwitted by another Mentat

Comment: @Valorum Correct. But you're missing the point: Yueh was in Atreides' service fir 6 years. Not even Suk doctor just comes and gets hired. I assume that one gets invited to  the Great House. Since the Harkonnen trap hinged on Yueh, he would be first to suborn.   Hawat was presented with red herring only later. Yueh's missing wife is a BIG red flag.

Comment: @NKCampbell Except for the fact that Yueh wife's disappearance would be THE first step in the whole plot, while Jessica was framed at the end.

Comment: @AcePL - they (everyone except Yueh and the Harkonnens of course) thought his wife was dead. Yueh said his wife was dead when he speaking to Paul in Chapter 5. Again, there was practically no reason to be distrustful of a Suk within the context of in-universe reasoning. And again, in Chapter 8, he is nearly on the point of rage when speaking of his dead wife and how she died when speaking w/ Jessica. In context, at the time, since he clearly hates the Harkonnens for killing his wife, why would he turn traitor, especially when he's been specifically conditioned to NEVER turn traitor?

Comment: @NKCampbell Oh, I see... My bad. I agree on principle. But the issue is wife. You see? Yueh said she's dead, fine. But that's actually a very good cover for someone who wants to not to draw attention to oneself. Especially since she probably died (10186) AFTER he accepted service with Atreides (10185). And last, but not least: Hawat didn't know what actually happened to her... That's why I'm of the opinion this is an important bit and an excellent spot by OP.

Comment: @AcePL - When it comes to a Suk Doctor, the status of the wife is irrelevant when it comes to determining his loyalty. Their reliability isn't on a spectrum from 1-100, it's on a spectrum of 100-100.

Comment: regardless, I bet Hawat won't mistake any other identies again....

Comment: @NKCampbell - Hindsight is, as they say, 20-20

Comment: @NKCampbell - technically, Hawat did not clear completely Yueh until Jessica mentioned that his wife was dead because of Harkonnens and she vouched for his hatred of them. So hindsight is irrelevant, he got a confirmation of Yueh reliability from a source so far outside his usual channels that it would be gold standard for him. If anything rule 29 of Seventy maxims of maximally effective mercenary should apply: *29. The enemy of my enemy is my enemy's enemy. No more. No less.* Valorum is right, Yueh is an example of failure of going with "widely accepted standards"

Comment: also @AcePL - worth noting that in the book at least (haven't seen new movie) the warning that there is a traitor in their midst and the actual betrayal seems to occur within, at most 3 days, maybe just two.

Comment: The book also points strongly to the direction that Hawat was starting to get a bit out-of-touch, but more importantly, he was put on the scent of Lady Jessica being untrustworthy...

Answer (score 24):

The answer by Valorum explains clearly why Hawat didn't put Yueh under stricter surveillance; the part of the question regarding Yueh's wife is addressed during a conversation between Hawat and Lady Jessica:

> "You know that's an empty gesture," Hawat said. "He's conditioned by the High College. That I know for certain."
>
> "Not to mention that his wife was a Bene Gesserit slain by the Harkonnens," Jessica said.
>
> "So that's what happened to her," Hawat said

This makes it clear that the mentat *did* investigate Yueh's past - he simply wasn't able to find information about Wanna's fate.

Answer (score 14):

It's not incoherent. It's very clearly explained.

Yueh had Imperial Conditioning, which is supposed to be unbreakable. Even if they had known about his wife - and he does in fact reveal it to Jessica at one point - they still would not have considered him a potential traitor.

Comment: In the book at least, that even comes in a conversation a potential traitor between Jessica and Thufir.  Jessica suggests (possibly not seriously), bringing him in for question after ruling out just about everyone else.  Thufir dismisses it as a waste of time due to knowing he had the Suk School Imperial Conditioning.

Comment: Kinda lame that the first guy we meet with this incredibly unbreakable conditioning immediately busts out of it.

Comment: @AdamWise It's like how Worf is always getting beaten up, even though he's supposedly the baddest warrior on the ship.

Answer (score 0):

They didn't suspect Yueh because he had had Imperial Conditioning to not betray the Atreides. However, Piter De Vries had manipulated him into not viewing his actions as a betrayal; Yueh had come to the conclusion that the Harkonnen were so powerful and determined that they were going to succeed one way or another, and the interests of the Atreides would be best served by appearing to go along with the Harkonnen plan to get an opportunity to kill the Baron and save Jessica and Paul.

Comment: This is an interesting perspective, not sure the book backs it up, but I guess it's possible to read more into the actions of the traitor. What is clear is he used the opportunity to set a trap for the baron, to kill him as an ultimate fallback.